# Nvidia Spark-XGBOOST

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nvidia, xgboost

I would like to use NVIDIA Spark-XGBOOST because it has python support, however I can't find any documentation on how to install it.
The GITHUB can be found here.
[NVIDIA-SPARK/XGBOOST](https://github.com/NVIDIA/spark-xgboost)

Answer (score 1):

The [spark-rapids](https://github.com/NVIDIA/spark-rapids) project is working with XGBoost and is actively being developed.  It's well documented and looks like a really cool project.